# CSS overflow on resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made a simple card with CSS. I'm trying to make it responsive but when I resize dimensions using DevTools, the card overflows over entire page. I know overflow property prevents this but I think there exists better ways to design.

**The problem:**
This is standard look of card

[image: This is standard look of card]

This is the look of card when I resize:

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening? or at least make them look good?

**HTML:**

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <span class="circle">
          <svg width="17" height="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              d="m9.067.43 1.99 4.031c.112.228.33.386.58.422l4.45.647a.772.772 0 0 1 .427 1.316l-3.22 3.138a.773.773 0 0 0-.222.683l.76 4.431a.772.772 0 0 1-1.12.813l-3.98-2.092a.773.773 0 0 0-.718 0l-3.98 2.092a.772.772 0 0 1-1.119-.813l.76-4.431a.77.77 0 0 0-.222-.683L.233 6.846A.772.772 0 0 1 .661 5.53l4.449-.647a.772.772 0 0 0 .58-.422L7.68.43a.774.774 0 0 1 1.387 0Z"
              fill="#FC7614"
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <h2>How did we do?</h2>
        <p>
          Please let us know how we did with your suppoer request. All feedback
          is appreciated to help us improve our offering!
        </p>
        <div class="rating">
          <span class="circle">1</span>
          <span class="circle">2</span>
          <span class="circle">3</span>
          <span class="circle">4</span>
          <span class="circle">5</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**CSS:**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,500;9..144,600&family=Overpass:wght@400;700&display=swap");

:root {
  --mobile-width: 375px;
  --desktop-width: 1440px;
  --btn-hover: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --rating-hover: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  --body-background: #121417;
  --card-background: #252d37;
  --p-font-size: 15px;
  --p-color: hsl(216, 12%, 54%);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Overpass", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--body-background);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

.card {
  width: 20rem;
  background-color: var(--card-background);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card h2 {
  color: var(--btn-hover);
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 700;
}

.card p {
  color: var(--p-color);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}

.card .rating {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card .circle {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #30363f;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--p-color);
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of `@media`? If not take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php).

Comment: Tested your code with plain html and css. And when putting the very narrow screen dimension as in your screenshot, it does not look like in your screenshot in my browser. The whole box gets resized to small.

Comment: @Geshode Yes,sir. I am aware of ```@media```. But i do not know what should i do with it.

Comment: @Peter206 Sir, i forgot to mention but i am using Microsoft Edge browser. Maybe it affects the results.

Comment: if no custom device is aimed, I think there is no need to support 88px width. Even apple watch screen is bigger than that.

Comment: @AhmetRemziEKMEKCI So sir, you are telling me it si normal?

Comment: Yes I think in your case it is normal.

Comment: In terms of perfect responsiveness I would suggest to better explore the property `flex-wrap: wrap` so that the buttons will wrap and wont stretch their size or overflow the container. It's true that you shouldn't care of a screen of few pixels.. but yet you should address the ranges... and maybe consider a different style given a checkpoint (that's where @media queries come into play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what device of yours has an **88 pixels** viewport width? That's not small, it's **extra tiny**. Even smartwatches are bigger than that.

After analyzing your code, to make it **fit** to such a **tiny screen** you need to adapt each sections that are overflowing:

- your pagination/ratings needs a `flex-wrap: wrap;`
- And the card's text need to be broken so you can either use `word-break: break-all;` or `hyphens: auto;`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,500;9..144,600&family=Overpass:wght@400;700&display=swap");

:root {
  --mobile-width: 375px;
  --desktop-width: 1440px;
  --btn-hover: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --rating-hover: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  --body-background: #121417;
  --card-background: #252d37;
  --p-font-size: 15px;
  --p-color: hsl(216, 12%, 54%);
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Overpass", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--body-background);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

.card {
  width: 20rem;
  background-color: var(--card-background);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card > * {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card h2 {
  color: var(--btn-hover);
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 700;
}

.card p {
  color: var(--p-color);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;

  /* ADDED HERE */
  hyphens: auto;
}

.card .rating {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
  
  /* ADDED HERE*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card .circle {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #30363f;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--p-color);
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <span class="circle">
          <svg width="17" height="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              d="m9.067.43 1.99 4.031c.112.228.33.386.58.422l4.45.647a.772.772 0 0 1 .427 1.316l-3.22 3.138a.773.773 0 0 0-.222.683l.76 4.431a.772.772 0 0 1-1.12.813l-3.98-2.092a.773.773 0 0 0-.718 0l-3.98 2.092a.772.772 0 0 1-1.119-.813l.76-4.431a.77.77 0 0 0-.222-.683L.233 6.846A.772.772 0 0 1 .661 5.53l4.449-.647a.772.772 0 0 0 .58-.422L7.68.43a.774.774 0 0 1 1.387 0Z"
              fill="#FC7614"
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <h2>How did we do?</h2>
        <p>
          Please let us know how we did with your suppoer request. All feedback
          is appreciated to help us improve our offering!
        </p>
        <div class="rating">
          <span class="circle">1</span>
          <span class="circle">2</span>
          <span class="circle">3</span>
          <span class="circle">4</span>
          <span class="circle">5</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```